# Finding dict objects with duplicated key values in array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that contains dict objects, one dict represent one record from my MySQL db. So I would like to find every dictionary where the value of the `title` key is duplicated, and then update the duplicated item.

So I have something like this:

```
dict1 = {"id":1234,"title":"apple"}
dict2 = {"id":1235,"title":"orange"}
dict3 = {"id":1236,"title":"apple"}
dict4 = {"id":1237,"title":"kiwi"}

results = [dict1,dict2,dict3,dict4]
```

And I'd like to end up with something like this:

```
dict1 = {"id":1234,"title":"apple"}
dict2 = {"id":1235,"title":"orange"}
dict3 = {"id":1236,"title":"apple 2"}
dict4 = {"id":1237,"title":"kiwi"}
```

And here is my attempt, that doesn't work. When I run it the if statement never be true. (Note: I'm using peewee and I'm getting the base array from database, therefore I'm accessing to the values like this `obj.title`, but I assume these objects can be handled as a simple dict)

```
objects = mydb.select().where(mydb.title.contains("usa"))

objectsB = objects

for obj in objects:
    for obj2 in objectsB:
        if obj.title is obj2.title and obj.objectId is not obj2.objectId:
            obj2.title = "%s Duplicate" %  (obj.title,) 
            print(obj2.title)
```

As you can see I have another key, the `objectId`, which is always different so it can be used to find the duplicate entries during the for loop. However I could't figure out the right way to do it, therefore I would really appreciate if somebody could show me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Does peewee not support `HAVING`?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `is` for string equality checking. `is` is used to object identity, but there are cases where 2 strings with the same content will exist as 2 different objects.

Comment: @TomDalton what should I use instead of `is`?

Comment: `==`, that is, equality.

Comment: Yes, peewee does support HAVING. I guess the person who asked the question doesn't know SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a `Counter` so you only need to iterate over the result set once:

```
from collections import Counter

results = [
    {"id":1234,"title":"apple"},
    {"id":1235,"title":"orange"},
    {"id":1236,"title":"apple"},
    {"id":1237,"title":"kiwi"},
]

title_counter = Counter()

for result in results:
    title = result["title"]
    title_counter[title] += 1
    if title_counter[title] > 1:
        result["title"] += " " + str(title_counter[title])

for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Which prints:

```
{'id': 1234, 'title': 'apple'}
{'id': 1235, 'title': 'orange'}
{'id': 1236, 'title': 'apple 2'}
{'id': 1237, 'title': 'kiwi'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use Peewee ORM + SQL to do the work for you?

```
query = (Fruit
         .select(Fruit.title, fn.COUNT(Fruit.id))
         .group_by(Fruit.title)
         .having(fn.COUNT(Fruid.id) > 1))
```

Then you will have a list that only contains the fruits where there was more than one with the same title.

Comment: Thank you Charles, it would be the best solution, however I can't figure out what is the `fn` from the `fn.COUNT`, I got an error that `fn is not defined`. Could you help tell me that what is that?

Comment: `from peewee import fn`